# Hadoop s3 configuration file missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm using the Hadoop library to upload files in S3. Because of some metric configuration file is missing I'm getting this exception

```
MetricsConfig - Could not locate file hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException: 

Could not locate: org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileLocator@77f46cee[fileName=hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,basePath=<null>,sourceURL=,encoding=<null>,fileSystem=<null>,locationStrategy=<null>]
```

My current configurations are

```
configuration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "accessKey")
configuration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secretKey")
```

Where to add this configuration file? What to add to that configuration file?

Answer (score 4):

don't worry about it, it's just an irritating warning. It's only relevant when you have the s3a or abfs connectors running in a long-lived app where the metrics are being collected and fed to some management tooling.

Set the log level to warn in the log4j.properties file in your spark conf dir

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2=WARN
```

Answer (score 1):

I just placed an empty file in the classpath and it stopped complaining. Like:

```
touch /opt/spark/conf/hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties
```