# PySpark job fails with missing dependencies when reading from S3 "SSLPeerUnverifiedException"

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, pyspark, aws-sdk

I am encountering an issue while running a PySpark job through a docker container to read data from an S3 bucket. Despite adding the required JAR dependencies for Hadoop AWS integration, the job fails with missing dependencies error. Below is my Dockerfile and PySpark script:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
USER root
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre-headless wget && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pyspark==3.3.1
RUN mkdir /opt/jars/


RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.3.1/hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar -P /opt/jars/
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.901/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.901.jar -P /opt/jars/
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.10.14/joda-time-2.10.14.jar -P /opt/jars/
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar -P /opt/jars/
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.13.4/jackson-core-2.13.4.jar -P /opt/jars/
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.13.4/jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar -P /opt/jars/
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.13.4.2/jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar -P /opt/jars/


RUN mkdir -p /opt/spark/conf && touch /opt/spark/conf/hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties
COPY query_s3_data.py .

#CMD ["spark-submit", "--jars", "/opt/jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.678.jar,/opt/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar", "query_s3_data.py"]
CMD ["spark-submit", "--jars", "/opt/jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.901.jar,/opt/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar,/opt/jars/joda-time-2.10.14.jar,/opt/jars/httpclient-4.5.13.jar,/opt/jars/jackson-core-2.13.4.jar,/opt/jars/jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar,/opt/jars/jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar", "query_s3_data.py"]
```

pyspark script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("S3Query") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/opt/jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.678.jar,/opt/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "<key>")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "<secret.key>")

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")

df = spark.read.csv("s3a://sample.datasets/random.csv")
df.show()
```

error message:

24/03/19 05:27:34 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 6de12a7eaf0e, 38797, None)
24/03/19 05:27:34 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
24/03/19 05:27:34 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/app/spark-warehouse'.
24/03/19 05:27:35 WARN MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
24/03/19 05:27:35 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
24/03/19 05:27:35 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started

- the job gets stalled here for a long time, then proceeds to give me this error:

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <sample.datasets.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy34.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1333)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
... 41 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/query_s3_data.py", line 14, in 
df = spark.read.csv("s3a://sample.datasets/good-datasets/Cabs.csv")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 535, in csv
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in **call**
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on s3a://sample.datasets/good-datasets/Cabs.csv: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Certificate for <sample.datasets.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]: Unable to execute HTTP request: Certificate for <sample.datasets.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:208)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3289)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.innerGetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3185)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3053)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1760)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.exists(S3AFileSystem.java:4263)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$4(DataSource.scala:784)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$4$adapted(DataSource.scala:782)
at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Certificate for <sample.datasets.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5227)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:6189)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:6162)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5211)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5173)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1360)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.lambda$getObjectMetadata$6(S3AFileSystem.java:2066)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:412)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:2056)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getObjectMetadata(S3AFileSystem.java:2032)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.s3GetFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:3273)
... 20 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <sample.datasets.s3.amazonaws.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.s3.amazonaws.com, s3.amazonaws.com]
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy34.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at com.amazonaws.thirdparty.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1333)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
... 39 more

24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://365675a28f3d:4040
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5c7bb4af-4a35-46f8-9248-45cfebb6577f/pyspark-5077c08f-89f8-4ba2-bfc5-b5940c64356b
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-4000837e-8a83-449d-90d9-3f97b43247f5
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-5c7bb4af-4a35-46f8-9248-45cfebb6577f
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
24/03/18 14:07:27 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.

Despite adding the required JARs for Hadoop AWS integration, the job fails with missing dependencies error. I have tried referring to numerous Stack Overflow articles and consulted the AWS support team. The AWS support team suggested adding compatible dependencies as listed in the official Hadoop documentation for S3A client.

Required Dependencies:

hadoop-aws jar.
aws-java-sdk-s3 jar.
aws-java-sdk-core jar.
aws-java-sdk-kms jar.
joda-time jar; use version 2.8.1 or later.
httpclient jar.
Jackson jackson-core, jackson-annotations, jackson-databind jars.
I have tried different combinations of JAR versions but still face the same issue. Any insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I've referred to a bunch of stackoverflow articles as wel but nothing seems to work.
one of the suggestions was to add an empty file in the classpath - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74182399/14879635
that didn't work either.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: disappointed with the AWS support team here; looks like they weren't actually Reading the error but instead just guessing "it'll be your classpath". We make a cloudstore config dump the first step of any cloud storage support call: https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a JAR problem. HTTPS certificate matching as `sample.datasets.s3.amazonaws.com` isn't matching `*.s3.amazonaws.com`

As the [AWS S3 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html) say,

> For best compatibility, we recommend that you avoid using dots (.) in bucket names, except for buckets that are used only for static website hosting. If you include dots in a bucket's name, you can't use virtual-host-style addressing over HTTPS, unless you perform your own certificate validation. This is because the security certificates used for virtual hosting of buckets don't work for buckets with dots in their names.

S3AFS uses the hostname alone; it is never going to be changed as it is a complex issue, and, and as you can see from the certificate problem, insufficient to address your needs. See [SPARK-32766. s3a: bucket names with dots cannot be used](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32766)

Fix: use a supported bucket name for your data.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!
I can't believe it that's all it took! I was breaking my head over this for 2 straight days now. I've gone through numerous blogs and Stack Overflow articles trying to find a solution, and it's quite astonishing that the resolution was indeed this straightforward.
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I Do have a follow up question though, how do I exactly know which version of these libraries and dependencies to use? This was a nightmare to figure it out because a particular dependency only works with a particular version of the other dependency. for example I read somewhere that hadoop-aws-3.3.1.jar version does not work with aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.678jar. I literally had to try all permutation combinations of library versions.

Comment: oh, https://mvnrepository.com/  always. for anything.

Comment: good to here it works, even though I was expecting that. This shows that the secret to debugging deployment issues is reading network/https error strings and learning what they mean, rather than delegating to SO or AWS support. We've all been there: learn to (a) interpret them and (b) not to trust the apps or their docs...

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights! You're absolutely right. Learning to interpret error messages and understanding their underlying causes can be a game-changer when it comes to troubleshooting. 
I'll be honest with you, the error message was too overwhelming for me to go through which is why I solely relied on external sources to troubleshoot the issue. But, like most times in life, the answer to most problems is right in front of your eyes and it was in this case too. Should've put some effort into reading the logs myself which honestly, would've saved so much of my time.

Comment: I don't see an entry in the s3a docs, hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md  ... why not create a hadoop JIRA and then PR to fix it.